# Find largest array element with a Comparator in Java

Tags: java, arrays, comparator

So I have an exam on Tuesday for *Algorithms and Data* but I can't solve this question from a past paper.

> Write a Java static method called greatest which takes an array of objects and a
>   Comparator object which can order objects of the array’s element type, and returns
>   whichever element from that array is greatest according to the order given by the
>   Comparator object. You may assume the array is of length at least 1. Your code must use no method from Java’s API except the method compare from type Comparator.Your method must be generic, so the array could have any non-primitive element type.

My Attempt:

```
public static void greatest(Object[] a, Comparator<Object> x) {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            x.compare(a[i], a[i+1]));
        }
    }
```

But as you can probably see I'm pretty clueless and I'm sure my attempt is wrong! Any help would be great. I have looked at comparator's online but they just seem to be for a specific data type whereas this is for any non-primitive element type.

Comment: Can you write down the 'greatest' algorithm in pseudo-code?

Comment: Start with the algorithm only. Try finding the biggest int in an array of int. You'll need a variable holding the biggest int. Then apply the same algorithm to an array of comparable objects.

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand why your teacher asks you to deal with generic types, which are quite an advanced and complex matter, if you don't master variables, loops, and basic algorithmics yet. This is too complex for your current level.

Comment: Maybe the topic of the task is generics not looping? The knowledge level of the rest of the class might be different...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is supposed to be generic and return a result.
Here is part of the solution, you just have to add a few things to make it complete.

```
public static <T> T greatest(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> comp) {
    T greatest = a[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
    }
    return greatest;
}
```

Comment: You should use a bounded wildcard for the `Comparator`'s type parameter, so a comparator for a super-type of `T` is accepted too.

Answer (score 2):

`Compare<T>` is a generic interface, as seen by the parameter `<T>`. T can be any class. Because the below method takes an argument of type `Comparator<T>`, it can take any comparator that implements this interface.

Note that the array holds objects of type `T`. This is necessary, because the `Comparator` only knows how to compare objects of this type.

```
public static <T> T greatest(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> x) {
    T greatest = a[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (x.compare(a[i], greatest) > 0) {
            greatest = a[i];
        }
    }
    return greatest;
}
```

Comment: Almost. Type parameter `T` is not declared and the method does not have a return type yet.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I forgot to add it after copying his method.

Comment: Improvement: Use `Comparator<? super T>` so that any comparator that is able to compare objects of type `T` or any super-type of `T` is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

1. initialize the current maximum with the first element a[0]
2. iterate over the array and compare the current element with the maximum
3. if current element is greater then maximum, it is the new maximum
4. return the maximum

Answer (score 0):

The method must be generic (in the text the "object" is used missleading). It also needs to return the result (in this case an object of the input type, but some solutions might instead return the index of the object).

So the function declaration will look like:

```
public static <T> T greatest(T[] objects, Comparator<T> comparator)
```

And then you need to find the biggest one. This is simply done by remembering the biggest one you have seen so far. As soon as a element was larger, remember the new one:

```
{
    assert objects.length >= 1;
    T pivot = objects[0]; // assume the first is biggest
    for(T o : objects) // no good way to start with second
    {
        if (comp.compare(o, pivot) > 0) // if o is bigger
            pivot = o;
    }
    return pivot;
}
```

The code is uncompiled and untested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static T greatest(T[] a, Comparator<T> x) {
    T temp = a[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length;i++) {
        if (x.compare(temp,a[i]) <= 0) {
            temp = a[i];
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: I think for the OP the method declaration is important. And the method should be generic.

Comment: So then change the Object to T. Simple. Hell, you could edit the answer isnot2bad!

Comment: It's not my answer. It's your's. I'm not your tutor/ghost writer. I've downvoted it because it's not complete and its also wrong concerning the generic thing. Fix it and I'll revoke my downvote.